# Confusion About Limit

Tags: calculus

How can I evaluate 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{1/\log(n)}}{\log(n)}?
$$
I know the answer is zero, but could you explain how to get the answer step-by-step? I tried to find the answer by using L'hopital, but, I ended up with confusion.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You may also wish to peruse some of the free online tools for evaluating basic limits, such as https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos , I will take your advice and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observation:

$$\log(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{1}{\log(n)}}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\log(n)} \cdot \log(n) = 1$$

which implies

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{1}{\log(n)}} = e,$$

a nonzero finite limit.

The denominator of the limit in your question diverges to $\infty$, so the overall limit should be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\log(n^{1/\log n})=\frac{1}{\log n}\log n=1
$$
so the numerator actually equals $e$.